# Angular: Reloading/URL navigation reverts to default route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular 1.3.10, ui-router 0.2.10, and Express 4.14.0 for a basic Reddit clone, and I'm having trouble with routing.

My (abbreviated) Express routes:

```
router.get('/api/home', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Meanit'
  });
});

router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/api/home');
});
```

My Angular state configuration:

```
app.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
          postPromise: [
            'posts',
            function (posts) {
              return posts.getAllPosts();
            }
          ]
        }                      
      })
      .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: '/views/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl',
        resolve: {
          post: [
            '$stateParams',
            'posts',
            function ($stateParams, posts) {
              return posts.getPost($stateParams.id);
            }
          ]
        }
      })
      .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: '/views/register.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        onEnter: [
          '$state',
          'auth',
          function ($state, auth) {
            if (auth.isLoggedIn())
              $state.go('home')
          }
        ]
      })
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '/views/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        onEnter: [
          '$state',
          'auth',
          function ($state, auth) {
            if (auth.isLoggedIn())
              $state.go('home')
          }
        ]
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
  }
]);
```

My folder hierarchy looks like this:

```
meanit
  public
    js
      app.js (Angular)
  routes
    index.js (Express routes)
  views (Angular templates)
    index.html
    home.html
    posts.html
    register.html
    login.html
  server.js
```

All the routes work as intended, but when I reload the page while on one of the routes or navigate directly to the route URL (/posts/579d17934b0f5f6b2ff5c72c), I'm redirected first to /api/home through Express (intended, I think) and then to /home through Angular instead of the /posts/579d17934b0f5f6b2ff5c72c route (NOT intended).

How do I force URL navigation/reloading to stay on the sub-route?

(I've looked at [AngularJS. Retain state after page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297941/angularjs-retain-state-after-page-reload?rq=1&newreg=ca6847e7430148cfa716de5d5b5671f8), but I don't understand how to set up the URL parsing/how to adapt the code from the accepted answer to fit my project.)

Comment: How are you handling your static resources (javascript, css, html, images etc)? Does express serve them or do you use another web server like nginx?

Comment: Not too familiar with express, but it seems to me that you don't want express to redirect the URL. When express sends you to /api/home, angular doesn't recognize it because it's not a state that you've listed, so you end up at /home

Comment: @kennasoft: I'm serving statics with Express (public and views folders).

Comment: @ChrisNewman: Sorry, I've added the Express routes to the main post. /api/home should render index.html, which contains my Angular app.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you need express to do routing? As opposed to just using ui-router and angular? I would suggest that you try to use one or the other. Otherwise, everytime you refresh the page or paste in a URL you will basically get redirected twice (once for express and once for ui-router).

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I did a little research and came across this reddit thread that might help. It seems the problem you have is fairly common. https://m.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/2f4858/angular_express_best_way_to_handle_routing/&ved=0ahUKEwjJobnyip7OAhWDMx4KHZ7sBcYQFggxMAU&usg=AFQjCNFpTNpTICPX8ugjzONEniUMX-bpKw&sig2=4erhj63CS5W83pMCTpPB5w

Comment: Right, that's essentially my solution for separating routes (Angular uses /, Express uses /api/). I think my question here is purely Angular, though, since Express does what it's supposed to - I included it just in case someone sees something I didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your problem is with express. Your catchall is doing a res.redirect(), which, I think, updates the browser url. I suggest you just do a simple sendfile() or render(), instead of redirect().

Your express server catchall route should change to:

```
//This is assuming the index.html file exists on the same directory the server is launched from
router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Meanit'
    });
});
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! I changed the Express routing to use res.render directly instead of redirecting back to the /api/home route, and now it works perfectly. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Glad we finally found the problem, and you can move on with building your app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I started one of my angularjs projects. In my case, I had 2 different servers running; one for the API, and the other dedicated to serving static files. Here is what my express static server looks like:

**server.js**

```
//server.js

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

//use very specific paths to the different resource folders
app.use('/js', express.static('public/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static('public/css'));
app.use('/img', express.static('public/img'));
app.use('/views', express.static('public/views'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static('public/bower_components'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
var staticExtensions = ['css','js','png','gif','jpg','woff','woff2','ttf','map'];
var deeperPaths = ['/posts']; //an array of deeper paths that need special treatment

//cater specifically for post, since it's deeper than other paths (relative to the other assets /css, /js etc)
app.get('/posts/:postId', function(req,res){
    console.log('fetching matched request: '+ req.path + '...');
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/public/index.html');
});

//any other request returns the index.html file, where angularjs routing takes over
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('fetching '+ req.path + '...');
    var filePath = __dirname +'/public/index.html';

    var requestPath = req.path.split('?')[0];
    var fileExtension = requestPath.split('.').pop();
    //if it's a static resource make relative to /public
    if(staticExtensions.lastIndexOf(fileExtension)>-1){
        deeperPaths.forEach(function(path, index){   
           //this is not a very reliable test, but it works for now  
           if(req.path.indexOf(path)===0){
               filePath = __dirname + '/public' + req.path.replace(path, '');
            }
        });
    }
    res.sendFile(filePath); // load our public/index.html file
});

// START THE SERVER
app.listen(port);
console.log('Website started on port ' + port);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Unfortunately, my app has the same catch-all (with express router) and it doesn't resolve the problem. I'm pretty sure it's an Angular issue of not saving the route state?

Comment: it's not possible for the state to still exist when the entire page has been reloaded. You may want to inspect using the network tab of chrome dev tools, to see that the server is not returning the wrong content. I noticed in my own case, that when the requested url is one step deeper than where the index file is (e.g. /posts/{id}), all my static resources start returning the index.html file content, which is the fallback. that's why it's necessary to map the specific paths to each type of resource.

Comment: Please take a look at the modified answer above. I know there should be a better, more standard solution for this problem, but this is what worked for me until I switched to serving statics with nginx. I just found this code in my repo. When I realized it was going to get messy handling angular urls like this, I switched to nginx.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding the fix. Say I request /posts/somePostId - that follows the first rule and sends the Angular app, but the catch-all also sends the Angular app except if a static under /posts/ is requested. How does the fix affect the behavior of directly navigating to /posts/somePostId?

Comment: apart from the `/posts` route, does any other route have this problem? Does a full refresh of the page `/register` take you back to the `/home` route?

Comment: Yes, the /register and /login routes have the problem as well. As far as I can tell, Angular doesn't know it's supposed to load a state - is there a way for Express to pass the route to the Angular app in the catch all?

Comment: So long as the url in the browser maps to a route, and express returns the content of index.html, ui-router should handle the rest.

Comment: After another look at your question (I didn't see your express server before), Seems your problem is with express. Your catchall is doing a `res.redirect()`, which, I think, updates the browser url. I suggest you just do a simple `sendfile()` or `render()`, instead of `redirect()`.